# PHP date() - how to display a date that is not today's?

Tags: php, date

The date() function in php returns the current time and date, for example

```
date('l jS F');
```

would return

```
Tuesday 24 September
```

In a calendar app i'm buiding, I would like to display seven dates, starting from the current day:
Tuesday 24 September,
Wednesday 25 September,
...
Monday 30 September

is there an easy way to do this with date()? If not, is it possible to somehow add one day to a date?

Thanks for help

Comment: [strtotime('tomorrow')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: You could have just Googled for 'php date()'.

Answer (score 1):

```
date('l jS F', strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code display tomorrow date

```
$date = date("l jS F", strtotime("tomorrow"));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the DateTime class.
today as 9/23

```
$date = new DateTime('tomorrow');

echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); # 09/24/2013
```

To set the time.

```
$date->setTime(12, 0 ,0);

echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s'); # 09/24/2013 12:00:00
```

In your case.

```
echo $date->format('l jS F');
```